# how to configure default TERM in screen session?

Tags: linux, terminal, vi, aix, gnu-screen

When invoke vi in a session inside SCREEN, I always encounter error:

```
bash-3.2$ vi perf332.db2
ex: 0602-108 screen is not a recognized terminal type.
  [Press return to continue]

[Using open mode]
```

After I explicitly export `TERM=xterm` or something, it works fine.

My SCREEN is running on a Linux server, and I SSH from there to a AIX server.

Answer (score 3):

The default TERM variable for screen is `TERM=screen`. This is what its supposed to be.

You might consider putting something like this in your `.bashrc` to change the TERM variable to xterm when its screen.

```
if [[ $TERM = screen ]]; then
    export TERM=xterm
fi
```

However I do not recommend doing this as this might confuse other application.

It seems vi does not know how to send commands to screen when the TERM variable is set to screen. The other way of getting around this would be to install vim which does understand how to communicate with screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `shell -$SHELL` into your ~/.screenrc file